# move position of any opened app in windows batch file without using nircmd utility

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

Is there any way to move the position of the opened application with any commands direct from batch file ( note: **I don't want to use nircmd or any other utility**)

eg of nircmd: 
**nircmd.exe win move stitle "a1" x y h l**

Same thing which nircmd does, can we get above output without using nircmd or any other external utility.

is there any command for it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In pure BAT you can't do that
You can use Autoit to do it very easily, with the WinMove function.

Comment: Autoit is an external utility (which OP does not want).

Comment: Thanks ! for the Great Info !!! I just putted this as example cause it's not possible in BAT.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in batch. However, it *is* possible in Powershell, which can then be called with a batch wrapper.

```
<# :
:: Based on https://gist.github.com/coldnebo/1148334
:: Converted to a batch/powershell hybrid via http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37780#p37780
@echo off
setlocal
set "POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%*"
if defined POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS set "POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS:"=\"%"
endlocal & powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "$_ = $input; Invoke-Expression $( '$input = $_; $_ = \"\"; $args = @( &{ $args } %POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS% );' + [String]::Join( [char]10, $( Get-Content \"%~f0\" ) ) )"
goto :EOF
#>

Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public class Win32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
  }

  public struct RECT
  {
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
  }
"@

$rcWindow = New-Object RECT
$h = (Get-Process | where {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq "Untitled - Notepad"}).MainWindowHandle

[Win32]::GetWindowRect($h,[ref]$rcWindow)

$win_width = 1280
$win_height = 720
$screen_x=0
$screen_y=0

[Win32]::MoveWindow($h, $screen_x, $screen_y, $win_width, $win_height, $true )
```